# Testing CSS at different pixel densities

Tags: css, testing

I need to simulate pixel density breakpoints. I use `min-resolution` and friends to test pixel density to determine what image to load in my CSS for things like headers and such.

But, I have found no solution to test my code at specific resolutions that mimics `1x`, `1.5x`, `2x`, `2.5x` etc. Do I need to own devices that run at those resolutions to test or is there an automated/non-automated solution to this?

Here's a sample of CSS code using `resolution`. I'd like to test (ideally automatically) whether a specific CSS rule is active based on the pixel density:

```
@media (min-resolution: 300dpi) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question and to anyone else interested it's possible do this in Chrome:

[image]

for more information see this [Google developers guide](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports). Although I would still be very interested in an automated solution to testing this.

Comment: I don't see DPR option in chrome mobile view. Did you enable it somehow?

Comment: Yeah you can click on the ellipsis on the far right in this mode and select enable device pixel ratio.